# Cannot post Tweets with Linq to Twitter using saved Oauth credentials

Tags: vb.net, linq, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I have no problems using the Linq to Twitter WebAuthorizer to post Tweets to Twitter if my end-users are directed to Twitter's Oauth page and returned to our site.  Using WebAuthorizer in this manner works great.

However, if I try to store the end-user's Oauth credentials and use them to Tweet, I get a 401 Unauthorized error:

> LinqToTwitter.TwitterQueryException: Invalid or expired token ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at LinqToTwitter.TwitterExecute.PostToTwitter[T](String url, IDictionary`2 postData, Func`2 getResult) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at LinqToTwitter.TwitterExecute.PostToTwitter[T](String url, IDictionary`2 postData, Func`2 getResult) at LinqToTwitter.StatusExtensions.UpdateStatus(TwitterContext ctx, String status, Decimal latitude, Decimal longitude, String placeID, Boolean displayCoordinates, String inReplyToStatusID, Boolean trimUser, Action`1 callback) at LinqToTwitter.StatusExtensions.UpdateStatus(TwitterContext ctx, String status) at External_WCPages_v12_Test_TwitterTest.StoredCredentialsSingleUserAuthorizer() in C:\TFS\SC\Weblink_Connect-Development\CWT\External\WCPages\v12\Test\TwitterTest.aspx.vb:line 177 at External_WCPages_v12_Test_TwitterTest.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\TFS\SC\Weblink_Connect-Development\CWT\External\WCPages\v12\Test\TwitterTest.aspx.vb:line 65

I am including the primary functions which handle the Linq to Twitter requests.  Please help, am I doing something wrong?  I have tried releases 2.106, 2.107, 2.108 and the latest changesets as of 9/19/2013.

```
    Private Sub BeginWebAuthorizer()
        'Comment: Triggered on PostBack

        mobj_WebAuthorizer = New WebAuthorizer

        Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New InMemoryCredentials()
        objCredentials.ConsumerKey = Me.ConsumerKey
        objCredentials.ConsumerSecret = Me.ConsumerSecret

        mobj_WebAuthorizer.Credentials = objCredentials

        mobj_WebAuthorizer.PerformRedirect = Sub(authUrl)
                                                 Response.Redirect(authUrl)
                                             End Sub
        mobj_WebAuthorizer.BeginAuthorization(Request.Url)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CompleteWebAuthorizer()
        'Comment: Triggered on return from the Twitter authorization page

        Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New SingleUserInMemoryCredentials

        objCredentials.ConsumerKey = Me.ConsumerKey
        objCredentials.ConsumerSecret = Me.ConsumerSecret

        mobj_WebAuthorizer = New WebAuthorizer

        mobj_WebAuthorizer.Credentials = objCredentials

        Call mobj_WebAuthorizer.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url)

        mobj_TwitterContext = New TwitterContext(mobj_WebAuthorizer)

        'Success:  This posts a Tweet
        mobj_TwitterContext.UpdateStatus("Test Tweet using LinqToTwitter WebAuthorizer ( not using stored credentials ) : " & Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub StoredCredentialsWebAuthorizer()
        'Comment: Triggered on PostBack

        Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New InMemoryCredentials
        'For Testing: Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New SingleUserInMemoryCredentials
        'For Testing: Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New SessionStateCredentials

        objCredentials.ConsumerKey = Me.ConsumerKey
        objCredentials.ConsumerSecret = Me.ConsumerSecret
        objCredentials.AccessToken = Me.SavedToken
        objCredentials.OAuthToken = Me.SavedTokenSecret

        mobj_WebAuthorizer = New WebAuthorizer

        mobj_WebAuthorizer.Credentials = objCredentials

        'For Testing: Call mobj_WebAuthorizer.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url)

        mobj_TwitterContext = New TwitterContext(mobj_WebAuthorizer)

        'BUG:  SingleUserAuthorizer doesn't seem to work with the saved credentials from database
        mobj_TwitterContext.UpdateStatus("Test Tweet using LinqToTwitter WebAuthorizer ( using stored credentials ) : " & Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you have your OAuthToken and AccessToken backwards. Here's the code you should use:

```
    Private Sub StoredCredentialsWebAuthorizer()
        'Comment: Triggered on PostBack

        Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New InMemoryCredentials
        'For Testing: Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New SingleUserInMemoryCredentials
        'For Testing: Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New SessionStateCredentials

        objCredentials.ConsumerKey = Me.ConsumerKey
        objCredentials.ConsumerSecret = Me.ConsumerSecret
        objCredentials.OAuthToken = Me.SavedToken        ' <= here
        objCredentials.AccessToken = Me.SavedTokenSecret ' <= and here

        mobj_WebAuthorizer = New WebAuthorizer

        mobj_WebAuthorizer.Credentials = objCredentials

        'For Testing: Call mobj_WebAuthorizer.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url)

        mobj_TwitterContext = New TwitterContext(mobj_WebAuthorizer)

        'BUG:  SingleUserAuthorizer doesn't seem to work with the saved credentials from database
        mobj_TwitterContext.UpdateStatus("Test Tweet using LinqToTwitter WebAuthorizer ( using stored credentials ) : " & Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString)
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, Joe.

My OAuthToken was not starting with [TwitterAccnt#]-xxxxx.  I threw some validation in to my method and immediately saw the error in my ways.

```
Private Sub Authorize(Optional UseSavedUserCredentials As Boolean = True)
    'Comment: Triggered on PostBack
    Dim objCredentials As IOAuthCredentials = New InMemoryCredentials

    objCredentials.ConsumerKey = Me.ConsumerKey
    objCredentials.ConsumerSecret = Me.ConsumerSecret

    If UseSavedUserCredentials = True Then
        If Me.SavedToken.Contains("-") = True And Me.SavedTokenSecret.Contains("-") = False Then
            objCredentials.OAuthToken = Me.SavedToken
            objCredentials.AccessToken = Me.SavedTokenSecret
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Incorrect credentials<br/><br/>")
        End If
    Else
        If Me.DevAccountToken.Contains("-") = True And Me.DevAccountTokenSecret.Contains("-") = False Then
            objCredentials.OAuthToken = Me.DevAccountToken
            objCredentials.AccessToken = Me.DevAccountTokenSecret
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Incorrect credentials<br/><br/>")
        End If
    End If

    mobj_WebAuthorizer = New WebAuthorizer

    mobj_WebAuthorizer.Credentials = objCredentials

    mobj_TwitterContext = New TwitterContext(mobj_WebAuthorizer)
End Sub
```